# How to configure naming conventions with clang-format?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions, clang-format, camelcasing, clang-tidy

My team is interested in adding a tool to enforce style guidelines for C++. Two of the best options we have researched are [clang-tidy](https://releases.llvm.org/10.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/) and [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

clang-format appears to meet nearly all of our needs, however one thing I have been unable to determine is if there is a way to configure naming conventions with clang-format. This can be done with clang-tidy using [readability-identifier-naming](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability/identifier-naming.html#readability-identifier-naming).

Is there a similar feature in clang-format?

Comment: No, there's not.

Comment: @273K: Thanks for the quick reply! That's a bit surprising to me. We may be forced to have both a `.clang-format` and `.clang-tidy` file then.

Comment: Clang-format is all about local changes to the code in a way that is irrelevant to the compiler. Like changing whitespace. Renaming variables, on the other hand, is a completely different thing, since its impact is potentially very global (think about exported symbols consumed by other libraries, or just multiple files). Clang format also does not warn about any thing, that is what clang-tidy is for.

Comment: The comment up is and should be marked as the answer.